# Difference between gradle build and gradle bootJar?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

What is the difference between "gradle build" and "gradle bootJar"? Why would I use bootJar if I can still create the artifact using build?

Comment: Good question Jiji, and also, you might want to use gradlew instead of gradle :-)

Comment: @jumping_monkey I have been using gradlew now. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`build` is a lifecycle task contributed by the [Base Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/base_plugin.html). It is

> Intended to build everything, including running all tests, producing the production artifacts and generating documentation. You will probably rarely attach concrete tasks directly to `build` as `assemble` and `check` are typically more appropriate.

`bootJar` on the other hand is a specific task added by Spring Boot Gradle plugin that, when the `java` plugin is present, attaches itself to the `assemble` lifecycle task.

> The `assemble` task is automatically configured to depend upon the `bootJar` task so running `assemble` (or `build`) will also run the `bootJar` task.
>
> ([Packaging Executable Jars](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-jars))

You want to use `bootJar` if you're only interested in building the executable jar and not interested in executing tests, code coverage, static code analysis or whatever is attached to the `check` lifecycle task.

Comment: you should notice that boootJar is enabled automatically only if java plugin is present

Comment: If the `war` plugin is added, then the `bootWar` task instead  is attached to the `assemble` lifecyle task, which ends up producing a WAR file, suitable to run it in a J2EE compatible container.